# Apache Geode to VMware Gemfire transition

Tags: caching, geode, spring-boot-data-geode

Most Apache Geode Spring projects have this [notice](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-data-geode?tab=readme-ov-file#notice). The notice clearly states
"VMware GemFire forked from the Apache Geode project and is not open source"

Does that mean if I upgrade from Apache Geode to Gemfire I need to start paying for it??

The notice also says all *Spring* related projects are still going to be open source. But what good are those if the real meat of those is not open source?

Am I reading the notice wrong?